# How should I get snowpipe auto-ingest working?

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Following is my snowpipe definition

```
create or replace pipe protection_job_runs_dms_test auto_ingest = true as
copy into protection_job_runs_dms_test_events from (select t.$1, t.$2, t.$3, t.$4, t.$5, t.$6, t.$7, t.$8, t.$9, t.$10, t.$11, t.$12, t.$13, t.$14, t.$15, t.$16,
t.$17, t.$18, t.$19, t.$20, t.$21, t.$22, t.$23, t.$24, current_timestamp from @S3DMSTESTSTAGE t)
FILE_FORMAT = ( 
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"'
)
pattern='dmstest/(?!LOAD).*[.]csv';
```

When I am executing the copy command manually, it is working correctly.

Anyone knows what might be the issue ?

Comment: Have you set up your Set up the SQS notification and are you sure that it's working?

Comment: @NickW I have set up the SQS notification. How can I verify whether its working or not ?

Comment: Do you want to load the same files twice? Without Snowpipe and then with Snowpipe?

Comment: Hi - I don't see a AWS_SNS_TOPIC parameter in your PIPE definition. Also, see the comment from @Marcel: if you've already loaded the data it won't re-load without the use of the FORCE parameter

Comment: @Marcel No. I was just testing it without the snowpipe. I want to actually load it with the Snowpipe auto ingest.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the comments to your questions you tested your COPY-command by loading the same files before without Snowpipe. This means your files have been loaded once and thus you cannot load them afterwards with Snowpipe. Reason: Snowflake prevents loading files twice by default.

You can add the `FORCE=true` parameter to your COPY-command to prevent this behaviour and load all files - regardless of whether they have been loaded or not.

More infos about the FORCE-parameter here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

```
create or replace pipe protection_job_runs_dms_test auto_ingest = true as
copy into protection_job_runs_dms_test_events from (select t.$1, t.$2, t.$3, t.$4, t.$5, t.$6, t.$7, t.$8, t.$9, t.$10, t.$11, t.$12, t.$13, t.$14, t.$15, t.$16,
t.$17, t.$18, t.$19, t.$20, t.$21, t.$22, t.$23, t.$24, current_timestamp from @S3DMSTESTSTAGE t)
FILE_FORMAT = ( 
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"'
)
pattern='dmstest/(?!LOAD).*[.]csv'
force=true;
```

Comment: I agree with your point. But in my setup I deleted the files after manually loading them. Even deleted the table and pipe and recreated them. After that I again uploaded the files.
The pipe didn't auto-ingest them !

Comment: Also looks like the force=true option is not supported in snowpipe !
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-pipe.html

Comment: Oh yes, you are correct. Maybe this tips under "Workaround" are helping you: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-considerations-load.html#loading-older-files

Comment: Another idea: Maybe your Snowpipe was set to pause accidentally. You can change it to resume with ALTER PIPE: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-pipe.html

Comment: The pipe is running.
Here is the status of the pipe 

{"executionState":"RUNNING","pendingFileCount":0,"notificationChannelName":"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:634443784403:sf-snowpipe-AIDAZHN6L4DJ5COBUI7KG-YUNEXICr7uzruI9GrubqGw","numOutstandingMessagesOnChannel":0,"lastReceivedMessageTimestamp":"2021-01-18T09:01:00.322Z","lastForwardedMessageTimestamp":"2021-01-18T09:01:00.361Z"}